# How to authenticate pgrfilemanager usuing CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, ckeditor, file-management

i am using ckeditor with pgrfilemanager and I woould like to add authentication to the filemanager using cakePHP is it possible?

Thx for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question regarding this issue. The difference is that you would have to use CakePHP classes as opposed to Zend Framework classes that used.
here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025307/how-to-use-zend-auth-to-authenticate-user-when-uploading-using-ckeditor-plugin-p/12049829#12049829) it's roughly based on [this](http://binarykitten.com/zend-framework/332-tinymce-and-zend_auth-simple-authentication-checking.html) to some extents