# how to use Zend_Auth to authenticate user when uploading using ckeditor plugin pgrfilemanager

Tags: php, zend-framework, ckeditor, security

Hello Good People !!

I have a web application (my first of this type) based on Zend Framework 1.11.12 ( upgraded from 1.10.8) using "modular approach" folder structure i mean by that all the modules are under `application/modules`. i used Doctrine 1.2.4

i also use `library` folder for all the third party libraries including ZF except 2: `CKEditor` and [`PGRFilemanager`](http://pgrfilemanager.sourceforge.net/). pgrfile manager for uploading files to images folder from an admin panel. 
here is globally my file structure.

```
/application
    /configs
        application.ini
        routes.ini
    /layouts
        /scripts
            /partials
                  *.all_the_partials_files.phtml
            *.all_the_layouts.phtml
    /modules
         all_the_module_folders
    Boostrap.php
/logs
/library
    /Zend
    /Doctrine
    /SwiftMailer
    /Abra //where all my classes reside
        /Model
            User.php
            Role.php
            other_doctrine_entities_class
/public
    /javascript
    /css
    /images
        .htaccess // added an htaccess file here
    /fonts
    `/ckeditor`
        a_lot_of_files_including_php_files
        other_folders
        /plugins
            other_folders
            `/pgrfilemanager`
                /php
                    auth.php
                myconfig.php
                other_folders_and_files_including_php
    index.php
    .htaccess
```

At the point i was developing this site ,i wasn't using Zend_Acl so the session_start() in `/public/ckeditor/plugins/pgrfilemanager/php/auth.php` worked fine for some time since pgrfilemanager came with a default authentication feature. but once i started using Zend_Acl i run into issues like `Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer Array` exception when `session_start()` is called from the `~~/auth.php` file . I initially thought it was due do the fact i wasn't using `Zend_Session` but apparently i was rather due to this fact [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658445/zend-session-clean-session-before-calling-start)  (correct me if am wrong thanks)

How to use it? Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i found a workaround about this issue, i thought i would share, maybe i would get better perspective.

The Answer for the `Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class has no unserializer Array` is clear now as Session does how which format to `unserialize` to meaning php had to know the definition of the object stored in the session.

Based on the file structure i created an auth file say `myauth.php` in `/public/ckeditor/puglins/pgrfilemanager/userfiles` i will refer to this path is `pgr/userdir`

```
$path = realpath("../../../../library");
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);

require "Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php";

require_once 'Doctrine/Doctrine.php';
spl_autoload_register(array("Doctrine", "autoload"), true);
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->registerNamespace(array("Abra_"));
/*$p seem to be empty throwing error on Zend_Config_Ini but returns the config anyway.I never figured out
*/
$p = realpath("./../../../../application/configs/application.ini"); 
try {
    //     $config = parse_ini_file($p, "production");
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini($p, "production");
    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($config->doctrine->dsn);
    $user = new Abra_Model_User();
    $role = new Abra_Model_Role();
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    if(!$auth->hasIdentity()|| !in_array($auth->getIdentity()->Role->name,  array("superadmin","administrator")) ){
        die("Not authenticated");
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
*/
$p = realpath("./../../../../application/configs/application.ini"); 
try {
    //     $config = parse_ini_file($p, "production");
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini($p, "production");
    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($config->doctrine->dsn);
    $user = new Abra_Model_User();
    $role = new Abra_Model_Role();
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    if(!$auth->hasIdentity()|| !in_array($auth->getIdentity()->Role->name,  array("superadmin","administrator")) ){
        die("Not authenticated");
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {

}

}
```

in `pgr/php/folders.php` and `pgr/php/files.php` i included the

```
$path = realpath("../../../../library");
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

at the top. then i included the `pgr/userfiles/myauth.php` in `pgr/myconfig` as shown below

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/userfiles/myauth.php';
```

I hope this would help someone.  thanks